# How to convert an existing php application using phlanger

Tags: php, .net, codeigniter, facebook-authentication, appharbor

The PHP application uses codeigniter framwork 2.2. How can we convert it so that it can be hosted in .net cloud hosting platform like [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/) which supports [Phalanger](http://phalanger.codeplex.com/) converted PHP code.

The PHP application also uses Facebook api for facebook-authentication which is not working. Not sure if this is the issue? `$facebook->getUser()` returns 0.

We are not sure which assembly reference is missing?

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Phalanger-enabled Wordpress repository](https://github.com/appharbor/Wordpress) which includes all the necessary steps to make Wordpress work. It should be a similar process for what you're trying to do. The diff from the base Wordpress installation is [available here](https://github.com/appharbor/Wordpress/compare/29b3dea12dac59fe56444c42c79bea08b0e1b3e9...master) and might give a clearer picture of what is going on.

The process is relatively simple - you need to bin-deploy all the required Phalanger assemblies and reference them in your web.config. While you're developing/debugging the application I can recommend uninstalling Phalanger and take a copy of the binaries, so you can quickly add them to you project as needed. This way Phalanger won't be available in the GAC and if you run the application in IIS 7 it will resemble AppHarbor's setup more closely.

Comment: Thanks runesoerensen, looks like we do have the required references , we cross checked. we are using facebook sdk 3.01

Answer (score 0):

Phalanger can't "convert" PHP apps, it's just a runtime layer to execute PHP code on top of .NET.